Django Object id's passed to the template are not the same inside the view function
When I am submitting the form, the question id's that are inside the view function do not match with the question id's from the request.POST.
When submitting the from, the print statements from the view function below are:

<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['token here'], 'question_15':
['option1'], 'question_17': ['option1']}>
question_4 question_5

Inside the request.POST the id's are 15 and 17, and inside the view 4, 5.
Everytime i am submitting the form, the id's do not match.
View:
@login_required
def quiz_view(request):
    questions = QuizQuestion.objects.order_by('?')[:2]

    user = request.user

    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(request.POST)
        for question in questions:
            input_name = f"question_{question.id}"
            print(input_name)
            option_selected = request.POST.get(input_name)
            if option_selected:
                # Check if the user has already responded to this question
                existing_response = QuizUserResponse.objects.filter(user=user, question=question).first()
                if existing_response:
                    # Update existing response
                    existing_response.response_text = getattr(question, option_selected)
                    existing_response.save()
                else:
                    # Create new response
                    QuizUserResponse.objects.create(user=user, question=question, response_text=getattr(question, option_selected))
        return redirect('users:gaming_quiz')
    else:
        context = {
            "questions": questions,
        }
        return render(request, 'general/quiz_template.html', context)

HTML:
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for question in questions %}
    <div>
        <label class="question">{{ question.question_text }}</label>
        <ul class="errors">
            {% for error in form.errors %}
                <li>{{ error }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
        <div>
            <label class="form-check-inline">
                <input type="radio" name="question_{{ question.id }}" value="option1"> {{ question.option1 }}
            </label>
            <label class="form-check-inline">
                <input type="radio" name="question_{{ question.id }}" value="option2"> {{ question.option2 }}
            </label>
            <label class="form-check-inline">
                <input type="radio" name="question_{{ question.id }}" value="option3"> {{ question.option3 }}
            </label>
            <label class="form-check-inline">
                <input type="radio" name="question_{{ question.id }}" value="option4"> {{ question.option4 }}
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>


What do you mean with "inside the view"? Each time you submit the form, you generate a new set of questions, with QuizQuestion.objects.order_by('?')[:2], so the next time you submit the form, questions will be different.

That is not strange, you submit again to the view, where you again query for two random QuizQuestions from the database, but there is no guarantee that these will be the same as with the GET request, in fact it is very unlikely that this happens.
You thus should, in case a POST request is made, fetch the QuizQuestions for which the id appears in the request.POST, so the opposite way:
@login_required
def quiz_view(request):
    user = request.user
    if request.method == 'POST':
        question_ids = [
            key[9:] for key in request.POST if key.startswith('question_')
        ]
        questions = QuizQuestion.objects.filter(pk__in=question_ids)
        for question in questions:
            input_name = f"question_{question.id}"
            print(input_name)
            option_selected = request.POST.get(input_name)
            if option_selected:
                existing_response = QuizUserResponse.objects.filter(
                    user=user, question=question
                ).first()
                if existing_response:
                    # Update existing response
                    existing_response.response_text = getattr(
                        question, option_selected
                    )
                    existing_response.save()
                else:
                    # Create new response
                    QuizUserResponse.objects.create(
                        user=user,
                        question=question,
                        response_text=getattr(question, option_selected),
                    )
        return redirect('users:gaming_quiz')
    else:
        questions = QuizQuestion.objects.order_by('?')[:2]
    context = {
        'questions': questions,
    }
    return render(request, 'general/quiz_template.html', context)


Note: Allowing getattr(…) [python-doc] to work with an arbitrary (user specified) value for the attribute is often (very) unsafe: it allows the user to obtain sensitive data you want to hide. You might want to check how you can limit the options to improve security.

